# parse array and get a given child element in yaml python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have yaml as below

```
environments:
  qa:
    east:
      appname:testapp
    west:
      appname:testapp2
  prod:
    east:
      appname:testapp
    west:
      appname:testapp2
```

And i want to iterate environments and pick key for agiven environment value.

For instance:
environment='qa'
region='east'

now i would like to iterate environments and pick appname under qa & east values

Comment: Why would you iterate over it if you already know what you're looking for? Just parse it into a `dict` and use: `your_dict["environments"]["qa"]["east"]["appname"]` to grab it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this? (Note that you need to put a space after `appname:`, otherwise the yaml parser takes `appname:testapp` as a string, and not a key/value pair)

```
import yaml

config_yaml = """environments:
  qa:
    east:
      appname: testapp
    west:
      appname: testapp2
  prod:
    east:
      appname: testapp
    west:
      appname: testapp2"""

config = yaml.load(config_yaml)

def appname(env, area):
    return config['environments'][env][area]['appname']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(appname('qa', 'east'))
```

As @zwer correctly stated: What you are trying to do it not "iterate" over it, but "look up" the data. In python, config is a `dict`, which is a hashtable data structure. You can directly access values by a key. Whereas in an list (=array) in python you need to iterate (=traverse) the data structure in order to find an item.